# Mapstruct self defined mapper AND automatically generated one

Tags: java, mapper, mapstruct

I understand `Mapstruct` allows me to define my own mapper logic, I am doing it like this:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class ProjectMapper {

    public ProjectInfo map(ProjectEntity projectEntity) {
        ProjectInfo projectInfo = new ProjectInfo();
        projectInfo.setName(projectEntity.getName());
        projectInfo.setDescription(projectEntity.getDescription());

        // Specific logic that forces me to define it myself
        if (projectEntity.getId() != null) {
            projectInfo.setId(projectEntity.getId());
        }
        if (projectEntity.getOrganisation() != null) {
            projectInfo.setOrganisation(projectEntity.getOrganisation().getName());
        }
        return projectInfo;
    }
}
```

It works just fine, but I also want `Mapstruct`'s generated mappers, but they have to be defined in an interface, is there a way to group up both of these mapper types?

Comment: What do you mean by `MapStruct`s mapper have to be defined in an interface? You can also define theme in an `abstract` class, `MapStruct` will implement all the abstract methods. I am not sure if your specific logic is really like it looks like, but `MapStruct` can generate the exact same method.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Untested. I used the following solution once in a Spring-Boot project using MapStruct version 1.0.0.Final.

Customizing standard mapping process is [fairly well documented](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#_customizing_mappings).

One of the way to customize your mappings are ['AfterMapping' and 'BeforeMapping' hooks](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#customizing-mappings-with-before-and-after):

```
@Mapper
public abstract class ProjectMapperExtension {

    @AfterMapping
    public void mapProjectEntityToProjectInfo(ProjectEntity projectEntity, @MappingTarget ProjectInfo projectInfo) {

        if (projectEntity.getId() != null) {
            projectInfo.setId(projectEntity.getId());
        }

        if (projectEntity.getOrganisation() != null) {
            projectInfo.setOrganisation(projectEntity.getOrganisation().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Then annotate the standard mapper interface with `uses` and exclude the custom mapped fields from the standard mapping:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {ProjectMapperExtension.class})
public interface ProjectMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "organisation", ignore = true)
    ProjectInfo mapProjectEntityToProjectInfo(ProjectEntity projectEntity);
}
```